# Vue - know when computed is done

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i have an array of items, coming as props, which are filtered with computed property. i need a way to know that the computed property is done filtering.

in case there are no filtered items, or items at all i need to display a message. but while the computed property is filtering the array of items, the 'no items' message is displayed for a second.

so is there a way to know when computed is done?

https://jsfiddle.net/6cdutrob/

```
<ul>
 <li v-for="(item, index) in filteredItems" :key="index">{{item.name}</li>
</ul>
<div v-if="filteredItems.length === 0">
   No items.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I notice that more than just **No items** is showing before the render settles, there is also a glimmer of **{{item.name}}**.

The best strategy might be to use a cloak directive as per this example
[How to hide raw content during loading with v-cloak](http://blog.vuejoy.com/3-vue-cloak-directive/).

**html**

```
<div id="app"  v-cloak>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in filteredItems" :key="index">{{item.name}}</li>
  </ul>
  <div v-if="filteredItems && filteredItems.length === 0">
    No items.
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```css
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8bgyf6h/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `ready: false` to the `data()` object, then set it to `true` after the filtering is done:

```
filteredItems() {
  var items = this.items.filter(item => item.name === 'NAME1');
  this.ready = true;
  return items;
}
```

Then, show your message only if there are no items *and* ready is true:

```
<div v-if="ready && filteredItems.length === 0">
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gq9b63xk/

Comment: i tried this of course. but eslint is throwing: Unexpected side effect in computed property